# Tesseract ChoiceIterator for symbols in words with mixed languages

Tags: c#, ocr, wrapper, tesseract, multilingual

language is "eng+rus" and load_system_dawg - "F", load_freq_dawg - "F".

My string for recognize: АFGБЦШE.
Result: AFGBLLLLIE.
I'm trying to find a settings in which the choice iterator contains the following variants:

```
A [eng], A [rus]
F [eng], ...
G [eng], ...
Б [rus], ...
Ц [rus], ...
Ш [rus], ...
E [eng], E [rus]
```

Now ChoiceIterator contains variants only for one language (auto defined in word)

I would like to completely disable the analysis of words and to receive information on variants for each character at all defined languages (eng+rus).

Is it possible?